# Gearman Manager global variable == NULL

Tags: php, gearman

I am using Brian Moon's Gearman Manager that allows me, for example, to send worker's to background. 
The problem I'm facing is when I want to use a variable that was defined outside of function by using the *global* keyword:

```
$var = 200;

  function worker_execution($job, &$log) {

    global $var;
    echo "global is: ".$var."\n";

}
```

This code won't output 200 because the variable is NULL!?

Do you know why how to enable *global* scope in worker functions?

I assume the problem is that gearman manager doesn't include the worker file as is... It's reading it and goes directly into the "worker function", but still, there should be a solution to get access the variable outside of the scope of worker function?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the entire code. If you declare the variable after calling $worker->work() for example, it won't be executed, as work() goes into infinite loop. I'm sure there is no problem with the global variable in the worker's code.

Comment: @Darhazer... I am passing a huge string of data from database as workload to worker... If I need to send the DB object to worker, I'll need to serialize it. Will that cause problems while unserializing it? All the methods will be functional?

Comment: what this have to do with your global $var. Where the $var is initialized - in the code that sends job to the worker? There is no problem with serializing objects and passing them to the worker. You know, worker should have the definition of the object loaded before it can unserialize the data.

Answer (score 0):

just note, refer to  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/CNbuTshWfXA, use $GLOBALS will work.